# How to retrieve text from UITextView set in storyboard using auto generated key in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, localization

I have a directory structure something like this

```
MyApp
|-ExternalFrameworks
|-MyApp
|-Storyboards
| |
| |-Dashboard.storyboard
| |-News.storyboard
| |-Social.storyboard
| | |
| | |-Social.strings(English)
| | |-Social.strings(French)
```

And suppose the autogenerated string is "hn8-xyz" sore some key in the .strings file.
I need to extract the value string associated with the key.

I've found the the method to extract the string that is

`NSLocalizedString(key: String, tableName: String?, bundle: Bundle, value: String, comment: String)`

What I am not able to figure out is, how to assign the bundle property in this method based on my dir structure ?
I am primarily a java dev and not an iOS guy, but I've got this fix to do. Pardon my lack of framing the question as per Swift terminology.

Let me know if more information is needed to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

For most apps, you only have one bundle, the main bundle. If you look at the declaration of the function:

```
func NSLocalizedString(_ key: String, tableName: String? = nil, bundle: Bundle = Bundle.main, value: String = "", comment: String) -> String
```

The `bundle` parameter has a default value of `Bundle.main`. You can probably just skip that parameter entirely.

Comment: I tried it . Bundle.main is not throwing an error. But it is not picking the text for the relevant Key. Rather it is just showing the Alternate text given in the parameter.

Comment: So where are the strings located? You might want to examine your .app target and see where the strings are located.

Comment: The strings are located as per the directory structure I've shown. They are in the file Social.strings (English) and Social.strings (France). I've used the method something like this NSLocalizedString("hn8-xyz" , tableName: "Social.strings", value: "dummy", comment: "Dummy comment"). I am getting dummy printed in iPhone screen rather than the text associated with the key in the file. What do you mean by .app target ? target is iPhone. I am kind of a noob here in iOS so pls bear with me.